# In a CubeMX-generated project, where is PCD_EP_TX_ADDRESS defined?

Tags: usb, stm32, stm32f3

I need to use the macro `PCD_GET_EP_TX_ADDRESS` from `stm32f3xx_hal_pcd.h`.

It is defined with:

```
#define PCD_GET_EP_TX_ADDRESS(USBx, bEpNum) ((uint16_t)*PCD_EP_TX_ADDRESS((USBx), (bEpNum)))
```

but using it causes a compilation error as `PCD_EP_TX_ADDRESS` is not defined.

I have grepped the whole project and the string `PCD_EP_TX_ADDRESS` with the results:

```
fadedbee@host:~/cubeide/f3-hid$ grep -R "PCD_EP_TX_ADDRESS" *
Binary file Debug/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Class/HID/Src/usbd_hid.o matches
Binary file Debug/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Src/usbd_ioreq.o matches
Binary file Debug/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Src/usbd_ctlreq.o matches
Binary file Debug/Middlewares/ST/STM32_USB_Device_Library/Core/Src/usbd_core.o matches
Binary file Debug/USB_DEVICE/App/usb_device.o matches
Binary file Debug/USB_DEVICE/App/usbd_desc.o matches
Binary file Debug/USB_DEVICE/Target/usbd_conf.o matches
Binary file Debug/Core/Src/stm32f3xx_it.o matches
Binary file Debug/Core/Src/system_stm32f3xx.o matches
Binary file Debug/Core/Src/main.o matches
Binary file Debug/Core/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_msp.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_i2c.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_spi_ex.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_gpio.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_uart.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_flash_ex.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_i2c_ex.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_flash.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_pcd_ex.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_pwr.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_tim.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_tim_ex.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_dma.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_spi.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_uart_ex.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_cortex.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_rcc.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_rcc_ex.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_pwr_ex.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_pcd.o matches
Binary file Debug/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32f3xx_hal_exti.o matches
Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/stm32f3xx_hal_pcd.h:#define PCD_GET_EP_TX_ADDRESS(USBx, bEpNum) ((uint16_t)*PCD_EP_TX_ADDRESS((USBx), (bEpNum)))
```

The presence of the string in many object files, suggests that it is defined in some location.

Where is `PCD_EP_TX_ADDRESS` defined?

Comment: I checked two of the `.o` files with `strings` and only found the same macro definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be declared inside of [`stm32f3xx_hal_pcd_ex.h`](https://github.com/cesanta/ccm-test-fw/blob/master/f303test/Drivers/STM32F3xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/stm32f3xx_hal_pcd_ex.h#L76).

```
#define PCD_EP_TX_ADDRESS(USBx, bEpNum) ((uint16_t *)((uint32_t)((((USBx)->BTABLE+(bEpNum)*8)*2+     ((uint32_t)(USBx) + 0x400U)))))
```

It probably wasn't included by CubeMX because CubeMX is crap sometimes. There are options in the export though to allow you to include more parts of the library be exported than the ones used by cubemx.

*please don't forget to set the right HAL include defines inside of `stm32<xx>xx_hal_conf.h`*